# Creating a timer if not already available - RXJS

Tags: rxjs, observable

I want to create a list of items which are coming up in a particular time period. When the first item comes up, I want to start the timer, and, till the timer completes, any further items coming has to be added to the same list. Once the timer time completes, need to get this total list. After this, again another item comes, it has to start with a new list.

How do I do this in RxJS?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can use a `bufferToggle()` and a `BehaviorSubject`.

1. Note that I multicasted the `randomIntGenerator`, which would be your asynchronous list of items.
2. You can manipulate the predicate`i > 5` suitable to your context
3. The `BehaviorSubject`'s state is used to ensure that `bufferToggle()` is only allowed to track ONE stream of buffer at any time.

---

```
var Rx = require('rxjs');

let tap = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(false);
tap.subscribe(i=>console.log(`tap...${(i? 'on' : 'off')}`))

let randomIntGenerator = Rx.Observable
                           .interval(1000)
                           .map( ()=>getRandomInt(1 , 10) )
                           .share()

randomIntGenerator
  .do(i=>console.log('emits: ', i))
  .bufferToggle(
      randomIntGenerator,
      (i)=>{
        if(i>5 && !tap.value){
          tap.next(true)
          return Rx.Observable.interval(3000)
        }
      }
    )
  .do(()=>tap.next(false) )
  .subscribe( list=>console.log('#newlist -->', list) )

function getRandomInt (min, max){
    //From MDN's Math,random() example
    min = Math.ceil(min);  
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }
```

See the live implementation [here](https://repl.it/@jonalogy/RXJS-Timer)

Answer (score 0):

This code will do it for you:

```
console.clear()

const getRandom = () => {
  return Math.round(Math.random()*300,0)
}

const timer$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)   // A stream of numbers
.map(getRandom)
// .do(console.log) // uncomment to see each number as it is generated
.bufferTime(5000)

const s = timer$.subscribe(val => console.log( val));
```

This one uses a timer and a random number generator to provide a series of random numbers. These are buffered up for 5 seconds and then returned as an array.

The process starts again a second later as the next number arrives

A codepen is here https://codepen.io/mikkel/pen/VyzEgb?editors=1001